# Giving me Error and it is difficuilt to do in recursion please help me

Tags: python-3.x, indexoutofrangeexception

```
def unZip(master3):  
    c = len(master3)
    sub1=''
    sub2=''
    for i in range(1,c,2):
        sub1+=master3[i]
        sub2+=master3[i+1]
    print(sub1,",",sub2)
```

Error is following on Python 3.4.3:
string index out of range

Comment: look at the range `1..len`, see that you try to access `i+1`, and read the errror message: "index out of range". You should probably loop only until `len-1`

Answer (score 0):

well you have `i` iterating to then length of `master3` and then in the loop you are referencing `master3[i+1]`.  So yes, that will be beyond the end of `master3`.  Since you are starting a `1` instead of `0` do you perhaps mean to use `[i-1]` and `[i]`?